# Html: Resize Image in FormButton

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to resize an image within a button which is enrounded by a `form`-tag.
But somehow the image is not affected by css heights and widths:

Html:

```
<form class="infobutton">
        <button type="submit"
            formaction="Resources/Documents/schnittprofilreport.pdf"
            formtarget="_blank">
            <img src="Resources/Pictures/info.png">
        </button>
    </form>
```

Css::

```
img {
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
    border:2px solid black;
}

.infobutton {
     margin-bottom:5px;
}
```

Comment: this looks good ... maybe you have another css that override this value ?

Comment: Seems to be working here https://jsfiddle.net/eqE9J/313/ please can you provide more details?

Answer (score 0):

**Quick and dirty**:

```
img {
    width:25px !important;
    height:25px !important;        
}
```

Probably there are other [more specify CSS rules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) for this element.

`!important` is IMO a radical solution. The bettwer way is to create CSS rules which are more specify than the others:

**More clean**:

```
.infobutton button[type="submit"] img {
    width:25px;
    height:25px;        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `display:block` or `display:inline-block` to the image.